# Where to define env variables and how to fetch them in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I want to setup third party script and I want to set environment variables for production and development like API username and password.
How can I define these variables in a secure way and how can I fetch it in controller.

Comment: Why not define the `Username` & `Password` inside respective environments like **development.rb** and **production.rb**

Comment: @Abhi Committing sensitive information like username and password to your source control is not generally recommended, so `development.rb` and `production.rb` are not a good place to store this info. @Vipin asked how they could do this _securely_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Add figaro gem to your Gemfile and `bundle install`

Run `figaro install`. This will create a file named **application.yml** in config directory and it will add this file to the **.gitignore** file so that git does not track this file and you don not end up sending the file to to the remote repo.
You put your keys in **config/application.yml** in this form

```
user_name: "very_long_user_name!!@$#!@$#$"
password: "long_password_7381a978f7dd7f9a1117"
```

Wherever you want to use the user_name or password

```
ENV["user_name"]
ENV["password"]
```

To set your keys on heroku run `figaro heroku:set -e production`

Comment: how about `ENV.fetch('user_name')` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new file called .env in the highest level of your app alongside files like your Gemfile etc. Then install the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) Ruby gem. Inside the .env file you can add your environment variables, for example:

```
USERNAME=my_username
PASSWORD=password
```

You can then reference these in your controller with:

```
ENV["USERNAME"]
ENV["PASSWORD"]
```

Comment: If you are using rails, also install `dotenv-rails`, which will add helpers that would make life easier.

Answer (score 3):

In-case if you are using Linux/Ubuntu machine.

Set environment variables by just appending

```
export API_USER_NAME=vipin
export API_PASSWORD=password
```

to your **.bashrc** file in */home/user* path at end of line.

...and in your rails application you can use

```
ENV["API_USER_NAME"]
ENV["API_PASSWORD"]
```

Make sure to restart terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brilliant gem that I constantly use for all of my keys/passwords/etc: [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) .

The gem has easy to follow documentation that should solve your problems.

E.g. :

**config/application.yml**

```
pusher_api_id: "2954"
```

**controller.rb**

```
@pusher_id = ENV['pusher_api_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

This working for me in html.erb file

```
 <a href="<%= ENV.fetch('variable') %>"></a> with fetch
 <a href="<%= ENV['variable'] %>"></a> with out fetch
```